# How to rotate text manim

Tags: python, rotation, line, manim

Is there anyway to rotate a

```
Text()
```

in manim
I have tried using

```
Rotate(Text())
```

it did not work .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear whether or not you want to animate it; `Rotate(some_text)` is an animation and needs to be `play`ed.

In the community edition, you can run `t.rotate(PI)` to rotate without animation, and the `Rotate` animation from above like

```
def construct(self):
    t = Text("Hello World!")
    self.add(t)
    self.play(Rotate(t, angle=PI))
```

to animate the rotation.